# Recursive Grep to show only total matchin count

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to do a recursive grep search such as:

```
grep -r -c "foo" /some/directory
```

which give me output auch as:

```
/some/directory/somefile_2013-04-08.txt:0
/some/directory/somefile_2013-04-09.txt:1
/some/directory/somefile_2013-04-10.txt:4
...etc
```

however, I would like to just get the total number of matches in all files, like:

```
Total matches:    5
```

I've played around with some other examples such as [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884591/grep-recursive-and-count), although I can't seem to do what should be so simple.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
grep -ro "foo" /some/directory | wc -l | xargs echo "Total matches :"
```

The `-o` option of `grep` prints *all* the existing occurences of a string in a file.

Comment: thanks, useful command. i'm not sure which is accurate though, since with your example i get 447 matches, and Johns I get 392. I'll have to play with it a bit more to know I guess.

Comment: This command has perfectly worked for me anyway. I've updated my example to add a string giving you the result when the command ends.

Comment: Multiple matches within a single line each produce a separate line of output with `-o`.

Answer (score 11):

Just pipe to grep.

```
grep -r "foo" /some/directory | grep -c "foo"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
matches=$(grep -rch "foo" /some/directory | paste -sd+ - | bc)
echo "Total matches: $matches"
```

The paste/bc piece sums up a list of numbers. See: [Bash command to sum a column of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096259/bash-command-to-sum-a-column-of-numbers).

Comment: wow. awesome command :) - is difficult to add "Total matches: " to it?

Comment: I ended up going with Halims, because it combined everything in one line. I'll definitely keep this one handy though, as it could be quite useful. ty again.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the total, you can skip getting the count for each file, and just get a total number of matched lines:

```
grep -r "foo" /some/directory | wc -l
```

Comment: This will only print each line where one or many occurences have been found. This will not return all the existing occurences of a string or pattern.